# Do you refer to a bonded atom as an "ion"?

Tags: bond, atoms

Take H2O, would you call the H a hydrogen ion? Or just a hydrogen atom?

Answer (score 3):

Answer: Hydrogen atom. 
Remember, the Hydrogen in this case is polar covalently bonded to the Oxygen. The Oxygen has not completely stripped the Hydrogen of it electron but it DOES have primary ownership. 
Take a look at NaOH. In this case you would consider the Sodium portion of this to be an ion. Because the Oxygen has completely stripped the Na of its electron so the two are now held together by opposite charges. [Na+][OH-]
At least that's how i like to think about it.

All the best,
D